# How can I update all products names via sql query in magento2?

Tags: magento2, database, sql

Hi I have a list of sku's of all products at my store , I want to update all the names of products I have on store via sql query with respect to it's sku .

There is a table name : **catalog_product_flat_21** and **catalog_product_flat_19** at my database

Just for checking I have updated the column of (name) in these both tables and refresh the caches but still name on site is not update !

Tell me if you have solution of this using sql query , Thanks!

Comment: product name is Stored in catalog_product_entity_varchar table

Comment: yeah i figured it out , but i want to update product names with respect to sku's list i have , sku's are stored in catalog_product_flat_21 and catalog_product_flat_19 table , where in catalog_product_entity_varchar table i have the names and its enity_id  , so if i want to update products names it should be wrt enitity id's possible , how its possible wrt to skus?

Comment: using sql query ??? you can also create custom script for that

Comment: yeah if possible

Comment: can you provide me sample script for that! thanks

Comment: how to get sku ?? i mean sku list on csv file ???

Comment: no script of to update all product names by using sku's i have defined on script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create Script In Magento Root Directory And Run Script :-**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

$sku = "This is Test Sku";

$product = $productRepository->get($sku); // Pass Sku

$product->setName('Set Product Name');

$productRepository->save($product);
```

**Read CSV File in Script :-**

```
<?php

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

    include 'app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

    $sku = "This is Test Sku";
    $CSVfp = fopen("your_file.csv", "r"); //put CSV file on magento root and add your file name

        if($CSVfp !== FALSE) 
        {

            while(! feof($CSVfp)) 
            {

                $data = fgetcsv($CSVfp, 1000, ","); //here you can get sku in $data object

                $product = $productRepository->get($sku); // Pass Sku

                $product->setName('Set Product Name');

                $productRepository->save($product);
            }
        }
    fclose($CSVfp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro , last question what if i want to update many product names with respect to its sku, like i have a list of almost 9k products sku's which i want to update its names , than?

Comment: you can get product collection with addfieltofilter('sku',array('eq'=>'your_sku')) and change name of that product

Comment: my question is that how to get sku in custom script ??

Comment: i have list of all sku's in excel file , i would manually write it on script

Comment: you can read yor excel file in custom script and easily get sku..... :)

Comment: how , can you update above script for that , i would be so thankful

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the script, use the simple queries to achieve the updates

Create one temp table say, update_names with two column "sku, new_name and row_id"

```
CREATE TABLE update_names (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sku VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    new_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    row_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

Import the csv file into the temp table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_path' 
INTO TABLE update_names 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Update the temp table with row_id (its used to find the product in eav tables since name was stored in varchar table with attribute_id 73)

```
update update_names un join catalog_product_entity cv on cv.sku = un.sku set un.row_id = cv.row_id;
```

Use the below query to update all product names to the new name in the temp table

```
update catalog_product_entity_varchar cv join update_names un on un.row_id = cv.row_id and cv.attribute_id = 73 set cv.value = un.new_name;
```

Delete the temp table, once you verified the new name for the product

```
delete table update_names;
```